# Deleting an array of arrays created on the heap memory using delete[]

Tags: c++

I created an array of arrays on the heap using `auto x = new int[F][N];` Creation works fine. However, when I try to delete the code using

```
auto x = new int[F][N];
for (long i = 0; i < F; i++) {
    delete[] x[i];
}
```

I run into Segmentation faults. As per my understanding, this is the correct way to delete an array of arrays. But clearly, I am wrong here. Could someone suggest a better alternative?

Comment: You did not create the inner arrays with `new[]` so you do not have to `delete[]` them. Only the "outer" array you have to `delete[]`. So it's just `delete[] x`.

Comment: There is only one `new`, so there should only be one `delete`. (`x` is a pointer to an array, not a pointer to a pointer.)

Comment: And this will clear up all the all the memory allocated by the new. I.e. [F]*[N]*sizeof(int) ?

Comment: @RalphLabado Yes it will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever was created with `new[]` must be deleted with `delete[]`. The arrays contained within `x` were allocated and initialized during the initial `new[]`. There's no need to delete them manually as their storage and lifetime is tied with the outer array. Therefore, all you need is `delete[] x`.